# How to execute script once OR enable/disable script programaticly

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

Is it possible to run a TamperMonkey Script only once ?

According to me TamperMonkey Script are always executed when the url location does match so I was wondering to know if there was a way to execute a script only once and then to disable it for exemple. So when I refresh the page the script will not be executed again.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.

You could use [`GM_setValue` and `GM_getValue`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php?ext=dhdg#GM_setValue) to save the URL you run on, and if the URL had already been saved, not re-run the script.

Comment: But what if I want to use 2 different script on a same url ? For exemple : I load 1page script is executed, I refresh the page other script is executed

Comment: are GM a kind of global variable ?

Comment: I think they're scoped to each userscript.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share info between scripts, you can use `localStorage`, **but**:

- Local storage is not eternal, meaning it can get deleted after a long time
- Scripts from the webpage itself can read the same local storage meaning they can compromise or detect your script (theoretically)
- Also, just like with GM_setValue, remember that you don't know in which order the scripts will access the value.